# cannot convert 'this' pointer... inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I get an error when try to call the function `string SetToString(StringSet aSet);` from an inherited class.
The header file for the base class:

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

#include <ostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
typedef set<string> StringSet;

class Item
{
protected:
    string  title;
    StringSet keywords;
public:
    Item();
    Item(const string& title, const string& keywords);
    virtual ~Item();

    void addKeywords(string keyword);
    virtual ostream& print(ostream& out) const;
    string getTitle() const;

    string SetToString(StringSet aSet);

};
```

Implementation file for the base class :

```
#include "Item.h"
...
string Item::SetToString(StringSet aSet) {
    string key;
    int sizeCount = 0;

    for (auto const& e : aSet) {
        key += e;
        sizeCount++;
        if (sizeCount < aSet.size()) {
            key += ", ";
        }
    }
    SetToString(keywords);
    return key;
}
...
```

When I try to do `string k = SetToString(keywords);` in the inherited class, I get the error : `Error C2662 'std::string Item::SetToString(StringSet)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Book' to 'Item &'`. How to fix this error, and why do I get it ?

Comment: You get that error on the line `string k = SetToString(keyword);`?

Comment: @immibis yes, at this line

Comment: Maybe you're calling a `const` member function from a non-`const` member function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Item::SetToString` is not marked as `const`, so it cannot be called through a `const` pointer or reference, or on a `const` object.

You seem to be trying to call it from a function which *is* marked as `const`, and which therefore can't modify the current object (`this`) including by calling non-`const` functions on it.

Either make your inherited function not `const`, or make the base function `const`.